# Binding XAML element to Singleton class members

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, singleton

So I'm going off this site: [Winsows 10 UWP: How to Read and Save Setting Easily - Edi.Wang](https://edi.wang/post/2017/9/8/uwp-read-write-settings)

I tried using

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <core:AppSettings x:Key="AppSettings"/>
 </Page.Resources>
```

but I get an error

```
Type 'AppSettings' is not usable as an object because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.
```

This is my AppSettings class that I implemented as a singleton, where the one given in the example is not.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Windows.Storage;

namespace MediaManager.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Singleton class for handing application settings data.
    /// </summary>
    public class AppSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static volatile AppSettings _instance;

        private ApplicationDataContainer _localData = null;
        private ApplicationDataContainer _roamingData = null;

        private static object syncRoot = new object();

        private AppSettings()
        {
            _localData = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            _roamingData = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
        }

        public static AppSettings Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance is null)
                    lock (syncRoot)
                        if (_instance is null)
                            _instance = new AppSettings();

                return _instance;
            }
        }

        private void SaveSettings(string key, object value, bool roaming = false)
        {
            if (roaming)
                _roamingData.Values[key] = value;
            else
                _localData.Values[key] = value;
        }

        private T ReadSetting<T>(string key, T defaultValue = default(T), bool roaming = false)
        {
            if (roaming)
            {
                if (_roamingData.Values.ContainsKey(key))
                    return (T)_localData.Values[key];
            }
            else if (_localData.Values.ContainsKey(key))
                return (T)_localData.Values[key];

            return defaultValue;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

        // List all setting here
        public string movie_staging_folder
        {
            get => ReadSetting<string>(nameof(movie_staging_folder), roaming: true);
            set
            {
                SaveSettings(nameof(movie_staging_folder), value, true);
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that just like the error says, my appSettings.cs has no public constructor; it's a singleton class. I can't figure out how to get the data binding to work with a singleton class.

Comment: Why does it need to be a singleton?

Comment: @Stuart From what I've read, `NotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't work correctly if not a singleton due to complications if multiple instances of AppSetting exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind local:AppSettings.Instance.MySetting, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

```
public class AppSettings
{
    private AppSettings()
    {
    }

    public static AppSettings Instance { get; } = new AppSettings();

    public string MySetting => "My setting";
}
```

Comment: I have AppSettings in a folder named services so I added `xlmns:services="using:MediaManager.Services"` and replaced `local:` with `services:` in the binding statement. I assume this is proper. I also used `Mode=TwoWay`, as I want to store changes made to my apps user settings. When I open the app, the text field is blank; as I would expect on the first run. But when I change the value of the TextBox, it reverts to being empty when the TextBox loses focus.

Comment: The cause is most likely in the `AppSettings` class. One issue I see is `ReadSetting` getting value from `_localData` when `roaming` is `true`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The trouble from my last comment was due to the local/roaming mix up. I get so caught up in thinking that I'm doing something wrong with the code I'm not too sure of, that I don't think to go back and make sure that the code I'm comfortable with is correct. I need to be more careful with copy/paste; newb mistake all the way.